# How do you add an li to ul as soon as the user signs-in

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, dom

I am new to this form, sorry if I am interpreting a question wrong.

Say you have a basic sign_in form that uses sessions to log users in and out. The list is already created beforehand and the style is simply controlled by the boostrap classes. So if you want to add a click-able li to the the end of the ul with the same css applied as to the other existing li's in the ul, when the user  is logged in. How would you do it?  And consequently remove that page from the ul when the user sign-out.

What I am trying to get is to extra pages on my menu only when a user-signs in.

**Background**

I did a bit of research and I did read about DOM but the problem is I tried to apply css to it and make it in line with the other pages but it seemed so in-efficient. 

example of me attempting this is below

```
<?php
     if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
     {
         echo " <script>
             function myFunction() {
                 var node = document.createElement(\"LI\");
                 var textnode = document.createTextNode(\"Water\");
                 node.appendChild(textnode);
                 document.getElementById(\"list\").appendChild(node);
                 document.getElementById(\"list\").style.color=\"red\";

             }
             window.onload=myFunction();

         </script>";
```

Any help would be great or even examples.

Comment: Where is your attempt at solving this problem?

Comment: Also, this is a very insecure way of preventing a user from accessing an extra page.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for any JavaScript here; you simply need to have PHP echo additional lines:

```
$loggedIn = isset($_SESSION['user']);  // store logged state
```

Later, in your HTML, just add elements depending on the state:

```
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <?php if ($loggedIn) { ?>
  <li><a href="members">members only</a></li>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

There are other ways to accomplish this result, like

```
<?php if ($loggedIn) echo "<li>...</li>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your trying to create a login button? Or manipulating a list of items? ul (unordered list) li (list item).

I would find a secure way to store the login information. (Data base access?)
Then in your php file somehow check that the user is logged in.
If the user is logged in then find the current list item.
Javascript `document.getElementById("menu-login-button");` tries to find a login-button. Then you could change the text from logged-out to logged in, maybe also change the href it goes to. etc.